# Create a random number array without having a number repeat twice in a row

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I'm new to all of this so I hope this makes sense. I want to display random images when a button is pressed without having the same image appear twice in a row. I have found similar question on this site with answers that have helped, but I am still getting errors in my code that I do not understand.

Here is the code for my image array at the top under the class:

```
var imageArray:[String] = ["yes", "no", "indeed", "nope", "ofCourse", "noWay"]
```

Here is the code I am using for the random numbers under the button *IBAction*: (there are probably mistakes in this I'm not aware of, like I said earlier I am a noob)

```
 var currentNo: UInt32 = 0

    func randomNumber(maximum: UInt32) -> Int {

        var randomNumber: UInt32

        do {
            randomNumber = (arc4random_uniform(6))
        }while currentNo == randomNumber

        currentNo = randomNumber

        return Int(randomNumber)
    }
    var imageString:String = self.imageArray [randomNumber]

    self.iPhoneImage.image = UIImage(named: imageString)
```

I'm getting *an error* on this line:

```
var imageString:String = self.imageArray [randomNumber]
```

It says

> "Cannot subscribe value of type '[String]' with an index of type
>   '(UInt32) -> Int'

Comment: You are calling the method without parameter - var imageString:String = self.imageArray [randomNumber].

Comment: randomNumber method expects a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
var imageString:String = self.imageArray[randomNumber(6)]
```

As you can see in your function declaration `func randomNumber(maximum: UInt32) -> Int` which means your function accept an argument `maximum` which is type of `UInt32` and return `Int`.

But you are using your function like `self.imageArray[randomNumber]` where you want to access an element from `imageArray` with `randomNumber` function.

But your function accepts parameter which you doesn't assign so you can use your function this way `randomNumber(6)` where 6 is a max value.

And you can change your max value as per your need.

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the error and ran, but there are still Images that are appearing twice in a row. Do you know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the random item to repeat you can remove it and append it back after the next draw as follow:

```
var imageArray: [String] = ["yes", "no", "indeed", "nope", "ofCourse", "noWay"]
var random: Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageArray.count)))
}
var lastImage = ""
var imageName: String {
    let newImage = imageArray.removeAtIndex(random)
    if lastImage != "" {
        imageArray.append(lastImage)
    }
    lastImage = newImage
    return newImage
}
```

**Testing**

```
println(imageName)  // "ofCourse"
println(imageName)  // "no"
println(imageName)  // "yes"
println(imageName)  // "nope"
println(imageName)  // "indeed"
println(imageName)  // "noWay" 
println(imageName)  // "ofCourse"
println(imageName)  // "noWay
println(imageName)  // "nope"
println(imageName)  // "ofCourse"
println(imageName)  // "noWay"
println(imageName)  // "yes"
println(imageName)  // "ofCourse"
println(imageName)  // "indeed"
println(imageName)  // "yes"
println(imageName)  // "nope"
println(imageName)  // "noWay"
println(imageName)  // "no"
println(imageName)  // "noWay"
```

Comment: yes this way it will not repeat.Great logic Leo..:)

Comment: I ran your code and ended it with                                      self.iPhoneImage.image = UIImage(named:imageName)                                      But it will still occasionally use the same image twice in a row! Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I am pretty sure you are not running my code as it is. It removes the last element so there is no way to get repeated

Comment: Is this right?                                                                                                         var imageArray:[String] = ["yes", "no", "indeed", "nope", "ofCourse", "noWay"]
var random:Int{ return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageArray.count))) }
var lastImage = ""
var newImage = ""

var imageName: String {
    newImage = imageArray.removeAtIndex(random)
    if lastImage != "" {
        imageArray.append(lastImage)
    }
    lastImage = newImage
    return newImage
}

Comment: The correct code it is at my answer. Feel free to open a new question if you don't understand or don't know how to use the code.

Comment: Ok, thank you! :D This all new to me so I have a lot to learn

Comment: It works perfectly! I was putting the code in the wrong spot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `GameKit` there is actually a built in random distribution that does this for you while still being uniform and pretty random:

```
import GameplayKit

let imageArray = ["yes", "no", "indeed", "nope", "ofCourse", "noWay"]

let randomDistribution = GKShuffledDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: imageArray.count - 1)

func randomItem() -> String {
    return imageArray[randomDistribution.nextInt()]
}
```

I suggest encapsulating this into its own type:

```
struct RandomNonRepeating<Element> {
    let values : [Element]
    let distribution : GKRandomDistribution

    init(values : [Element]) {
        self.values = values
        distribution = GKShuffledDistribution(
            lowestValue: 0, highestValue: values.count - 1)
    }

    func next() -> Element {
        return values[distribution.nextInt()]
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
let x = RandomNonRepeating(values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

for _ in 0...30 {
    x.next()
}
```

gives

```
4
3
2
1
5
2
4
3
1
5
4
3
2
1
5
3
1
2
4
5
4
1
3
2
5
4
3
1
2
5
3
```